# Node generate-schema missing additionalProperties

Tags: json, node.js

I am using [generate-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-schema) to generate json schema for my data object. However, I am getting all useful properties except for **additionalProperties**. How to add this to the generate schema?

I am using it as below. Here dataObj is an object

```
var GenerateSchema = require('generate-schema');

var schema = GenerateSchema.json(dataObj);
```

Comment: related : https://github.com/nijikokun/generate-schema/issues/3

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bertrand.